# Is there a database of computer connector pinout / form factor diagrams?

Tags: icons, connector

## Background

I am making an open-source node-editor program for planning networks of devices (https://github.com/connorjak/Connectatron), and I need correct diagrams for over 100 common computer-related connectors to include in the UI. Here is a screenshot of its current state:

[image: Screenshot from Connectatron]

## Progress

I have searched with various terms close to "computer port icon set", and I have had some success so far, with icons like these:

- https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/159146-free-ports-icons-vector
- https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/159586-usb-port-icon

But, these only cover a limited set of the full list of connectors I want to support in my application, and many of the icons are too low in detail to not be ambiguous.

Some wikipedia articles on these connectors include form factor diagrams, but there is no better method to gather these than screenshotting them individually, and there is not a consistent style in the diagrams across articles.

[image: C15 plug diagram]
[image: nema5-20 diagram]

Full list of connectors at this time (my apologies for the C++ formatting):

```
// Variable name to string parsing:
// _    : .
// __   : (space) 
// ___  : -
// ____ : /
enum class PinType
{
    Proprietary, // For connectors that don't match any listed options
    Wireless,
    // DC Power
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector
    DC__Power__Barrel, //This is the generic one; we also have more specific specs
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIAJ_connector
    EIAJ___01,
    EIAJ___02,
    EIAJ___03,
    EIAJ___04,  // AKA JSBP 4             
    EIAJ___05,  // AKA JSBP 5
    IEC__60130___10__Type__A__2_1mm__ID,
    IEC__60130___10__Type__A__2_5mm__ID,
    IEC__60130___10__Type__B__2_1mm__ID,
    IEC__60130___10__Type__B__2_5mm__ID,
    IEC__60130___10__Type__C,
    IEC__60130___10__Type__D,
    IEC__60130___10__Type__E,
    DIN__45323__5mm__OD,
    DIN__45323__6mm__OD,
    Molex,
    SATA__Power,
    SATA__Power__Slimline,
    
    // AC Power
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector
    // 120VAC
    NEMA__5___15, //Typical outlet, 3 prong
    NEMA__5___20, 
    NEMA__5___30,  
    NEMA__5___50,
    NEMA__TT___30,
    NEMA__L5___15,
    NEMA__L5___20,
    NEMA__L5___30,
    NEMA__1___15, //Old outlet, 2 prong
    // 120/240VAC
    NEMA__14___20,
    NEMA__14___30, //Clothes Dryer
    NEMA__14___50, //Electric Oven
    NEMA__14___60,
    NEMA__L14___20,
    NEMA__L14___30,
    // 240VAC
    NEMA__6___15,
    NEMA__6___20,
    NEMA__6___30,
    NEMA__6___50,
    NEMA__10___30,
    NEMA__10___50,
    // Welder or Plasma Cutter
    NEMA__L6___15,
    NEMA__L6___20,
    NEMA__L6___30,
    NEMA__L6___50,
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320
    C1____C2,
    //C3____C4, // has been withdrawn from the standard
    C5____C6,
    C7____C8,
    C9____C10,
    //C11____C12, // has been withdrawn from the standard
    C13____C14,
    C15____C16,
    C15A____C16A,
    C17____C18,
    C19____C20,
    C21____C22,
    C23____C24,
    //TODO other AC connectors

    // USB          // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB
    USB___A,
    USB___A__SuperSpeed, // Has more pins for USB3 features. Fits with USB-A.
    USB___B,
    USB___B__SuperSpeed, // Has more pins for USB3 features. Taller than USB-B.
    USB___C,
    USB__Mini___A,
    USB__Mini___B,
    USB__Mini___AB,
    USB__Micro___A,
    USB__Micro___B,
    USB__Micro___AB,
    USB__Micro___B__SuperSpeed, // Has more pins for USB3 features. Wider than USB Micro-B.

    // Display
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort
    DisplayPort,
    Mini__DisplayPort,
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI
    HDMI,
    Mini__HDMI,
    Micro__HDMI,
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface
    DVI___D,
    DVI___A,
    DVI___I,
    Mini___DVI,     // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI
    Micro___DVI,    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-DVI
    VGA,
    Mini___VGA,

    // Audio
    Audio3_5mm, //Should probably specify stereo/not?
    XLR, //?
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK
    TOSLINK,
    Mini___TOSLINK,

    // DIN          // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector

    // Mini-DIN     // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector
    PS____2,        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port
    //TODO others from wiki article

    // Other
    SATA,
    Micro__SATA,
    eSATA,
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card
    SD,
    miniSD,
    microSD,
    SFF___8639,
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack
    RJ11,
    RJ14,
    RJ25,
    RJ45, //AKA 8P8C
};
```

## Question

Where could I find a set of diagrams/icons that fit these requirements?

1. Match the form factor of the connector closely enough to distinguish from others.
2. Self-consistent style, within reason.

---

A note responding to the previous close reason: I disagree that this question is off-topic. There is no software or service to be recommended here. Answers to this question would not be opinion-based and would not become outdated, as they would likely link to long-lived standards databases.

Comment: "There is no software or service to be recommended here." -You are requesting us to provide you with a service and/or database that has the images. Some questions despite being well written are simply not within scope at Stack Exchange communities. This is an example of one of those questions. I believe the close reason I selected, was that it was simply out of scope, I disagree with the system that not all close reasons are shown to the author of the question. Due to the specific request for a resource, that provides images, I see any way to edit this question so it's within scope here at SU.